# Topology of parameter space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

How do we decide the topology of the parameter space? Does this topology depends on the Hamiltonian (the form of potential) we are using?

I was studying Berry's phase and it involves rotation of the Hamiltonian in the parameter space which for polarisation is a perfect sphere and we get the geometric phase as $\frac{\Omega}{2}$ for spin half particles. What if the parameter space is not a perfect sphere but some other geometry say toroid or something else.

P.S: I don't have any knowledge of the topology concept.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that really does depend on the specific problem you are studying. In general one can only say that we have some "space"/manifold of control parameters $\mathcal{M}$. Three different problems where the parameter space have different topologies:

1. Spin in a magnetic field:

The Hamiltonian is given by $$H = \frac{B.\sigma}{2}$$ where $|B|=1$ so naturally the parameter space is the two-sphere, $S^2$.

2. Particle on a ring, in the presence of a solenoid going through the middle:

Now the Hamiltonian is $$H = \frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{d}{d\phi} - e \,\theta\right)^2.$$ Since the flux is naturally a periodic variable $\theta$ your parameter space should be viewed as $S^1$. In fact if the particle was moving on the surface of a torus, I could turn on two magnetic fluxes, one going through the hole of the torus, the other going through the torus itself and so the parameter space is like you suggest a two-torus now.

3. More simply you might even ask what happens as I vary the frequency $\omega$ in my Harmonic oscillator problem. I'm okay as long as I don't set it to zero, so here the parameter space is $\mathbb{R}_{>0}.$